# Mailform with DIV

Tags: css, email, mailto, mail-form

I am trying making a mailform , but it doesn't work , the last 3 code lines had tried and no luck, could you help? Thank you!

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <h4 class="wow fadeIn animated">Send us a <span>Message</span></h4>

    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group wow fadeIn animated">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <!-- /.form-group -->

        <div class="form-group wow fadeIn animated">
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <!-- /.form-group -->


        <div class="form-group wow fadeIn animated">
            <label for="message">Message: </label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
        <!-- /.form-group -->

        <input type="submit" class='btn btn-default wow fadeIn animated' value="email" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:info@millenniumcryptomining.com'">
        <button class="form-group wow fadeIn animated" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button onclick="location.href='mailto:info@millenniumcryptomining.com';">Send mail</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you test `<form action="mailto:mail@host.tld">...<input type="submit"></form>` already?

Comment: I have tried...............         <form action="mailto:mail@host.host"><input type="submit" class='btn btn-default wow fadeIn animated'</form>>   ............ and no work